# Populating a combobox in php from sparql endpoint

Tags: php, sparql

I am trying to populate data to a combobox using SPARQL. 
The code I am trying:

```
<select>
    <?php 
        $sparql = "PREFIX : <http://localhost/soy_test1#>
                    select ?X where {?PlantDescriptor :hasTOC ?X}";

        $result = sparql_query( $sparql ); 
        if( !$result ) { print sparql_errno() . ": " . sparql_error(). "\n"; exit; }

        $fields = sparql_field_array( $result );

        while( $row = sparql_fetch_array( $result ) )
        {
            foreach( $fields as $field )
            {
                //echo $row[$field];
                echo "<option value=$row[$field]></option>";
            }

        }
    ?>
</select>
```

But it retrieves nothing. I have been looking for any kind of solution for this, but there's nothing I could find.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you see in generated html?

Comment: a blank combobox appears..

Comment: Maybe - there's not result for your query? Check values of `$fields`, of a `$row` on each iteration.

Comment: No, there are values, i checked printing $row[$field] it retrieved the values, the problem is I couldn't find a way to include a sparql variable inside the <options> tag.

Comment: Once again - if you open __source__ code of generated html - what do you see?

Comment: And btw - why do you do not set any text for option like `<option value="val here">TEXT</option>`?

Comment: Yes, I could, but if I manually set the value, then what's the point of using an ontology as a backend.

Comment: Then how do you expect the value to appear?